# How to generate the Alter,Update & Create Script in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express

Hi I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2, I have 2 databases

```
1] ABC (with only structure like schemas, tables but no data in the table) 
2] ABC1 (with schemas, tables and data in the tables)
```

I did the comparision at Schema and Tables level, I found a table altered in #2 but not in #1 ,I want to know how can I generate the alter script to alter table in #1 ? And how can I generate the Alter,Update & Create Script which are missing in #1 ?
1st is the old DB and #2 is new .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [software for compare same DB schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12157613/1407421). this software after compare database schema between multi DB, get you script for unifying DBs.

for example in redgate software :

[image]

1. See Compare result for selected object
2. select object that want to unify
3. start unifying dbs

Answer (score 3):

The `ALTER To` option is disabled in the Script Table as menu option! So if you want to generate a script, how do you go about doing it? Well, you can’t do it this way when you alter a table.

In order to generate the script, you first right-click on the table you want to alter and choose Design.

> [image]

Now go ahead and add your new columns, change the field types etc. Once your changes are done, you want to right-click on any column or in the white space and you’ll see the option Generate Change Script is now available.

> [image]

Now go ahead and save that file and you’ll have your ALTER TABLE script!

Source: [How to Generate an Alter Table Script in SQL](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/script-table-as-alter-to-disabled/)

Comment: i have to right dynamic query for this that query compares the Schema & table if there is missing then it will generate a script to update and make the DB equal to New DB.

Answer (score 1):

As SSMS says, you will want to review the script, but all you need to do is Right click the table in #2, choose Script Table as > DROP And Create To > File...

Then run the script on #1.

Depending on how much data you have in #2 (and the likelihood you missed some differences between the two databases), it might be easier to restore a backup of #2 and then run a script that truncates all the tables.